# How to use .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $viewModel.loginSuccessful) with a non bool value

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, property-wrapper-published

I've got a view that uses the following view modifier:

```
        .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $viewModel.user) {
```

This will generate a error:

```
Cannot convert value of type 'Binding<User?>' to expected argument type 'Binding<Bool>'
```

When the user taps the login button, it will trigger a call to an async method in the viewModel that will set its user property if the login was successful or set its error property if not.

ViewModel:

```
class LoginViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var user:User?
    @Published var error:Error?

...
}
```

I know I can create a couple of `bool` `published` vars, but I would like to avoid having to places where I acknowledge a user has logged successfully ( with the User object and a bool )

Thanks

Comment: Use `fullScreenCover(item:)` instead

Comment: Oh my god, such a silly thing. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Using the [`fullScreenCover(item:onDismiss:content:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/fullscreencover(item:ondismiss:content:)) method should do what you want it to.

Generally I would recommend making an `enum` like this though:

```
enum UserState {
    case user(User)
    case error(Error)
}

@Published var userState: UserState
```

The benefit is that this will prevent you from getting into a bad state where both `user` *and* `error` are present.

Adding a computed boolean variable that returns whether `userState` is currently `.user` would allow you to use your current `fullScreenCover` initialization without adding a second source of truth.

As a side note, you could also use a tool like PointFree's [SwiftUI Navigation](https://github.com/pointfreeco/swiftui-navigation) to use the enum value directly for presenting the sheet:

```
.fullscreenCover(
  unwrapping: $viewModel.userState,
  case: /UserState.user
) { $user in 
  // View
}
```

Comment:  for the recommendation of using PointFree's navigation tools.

Comment: I love their approach to creating Swift tools, they've come up with some really great stuff!

Comment: Wow nice advise, much prefer it. Thanks @mimo. Just one question, if I add the computed boolean variable and I use it in the `fullScreenCover(isPresented:` method I will get a error: `Cannot assign to property: 'isUserLoggedIn' is a get-only property`

Answer (score 0):

You can add an extension to `Binding` like this...

```
extension Binding {
  public func isPresent<Wrapped>() -> Binding<Bool> where Value == Wrapped? {
    .init(
      get: { self.wrappedValue != nil },
      set: { isPresent in
        if !isPresent {
          wrappedValue = nil
        }
      }
    )
  }
}
```

And then you can turn your `Binding<Optional<T>>` into a `Binding<Bool>`

You can use it like...

```
.fullScreenCover(isPresented: $viewModel.user.isPresent()) {
```